# Use of Sum with Group By when using Left Join for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, left-join

I have 4 tables to join.

Sub_Category

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Monitor |
| 2 | Laptop |
| 3 | Mouse |

Products

| ID | NAME | SUBCATEGORY_ID | AVAILABLE_QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | LG | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | Dell | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | HP Probook | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | Asus | 1 | 3 |

Orders

| ID | PRODUCTS_ID | ORDER_QTY | USER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

Dead Stock (Damaged Products)

| ID | PRODUCTS_ID | Dead_qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |

I want the sum of all product quantity (qty) of each subcategory along with the sum of orders quantity and dead stock quantity that relates to that individual subcategory.

| Sub_category_name | Available_qty (sum) | Order_qty | Dead_qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monitor | 12 | 6 | 3 |
| Laptop | 2 |  | 1 |
| Mouse |  |  |  |

My query that is not working:

```
select
    s.id, s.name, COALESCE(sum(p.qty),0) produtcs_avail,
    d1.orderqty, d2.deadqty
from subcategories s 
left join products p on p.subcategory_id= s.id 
left join (select oi.product_id, sum(oi.qty) as orderqty
    from orders_item oi
    group by oi.product_id
    ) d1 on d1.product_id=p.id 
left join (select d.product_id, sum(d.qty) as deadqty
    from dead_stocks d
    group by d.product_id
    ) d2 on d2.product_id=p.id 
group by s.id
```

It returns:

| Sub_category_name | Available_qty (sum) | Order_qty | Dead_qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monitor | 12 | 3 | 3 |
| Laptop | 0 |  |  |
| Mouse | 0 |  |  |

Comment: At first sight, Columns in the group by (s.id, p.id) should be in the select list, otherwise gives an error.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE subcategories (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO subcategories VALUES
(1,'Monitor'),(2,'Laptop'),(3,'Mouse');

CREATE TABLE products (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(30),SUBCATEGORY_ID INT, AVAILABLE_QTY INT);
INSERT INTO products VALUES
(1,'LG',1,4),   
(2,'Dell',1,5),
(3,'HP Probook',2,2),
(4,'Asus',1,3);

CREATE TABLE orders_item (ID INT, PRODUCTS_ID INT, ORDER_QTY INT, USER_ID INT);
INSERT INTO orders_item VALUES
(1,1,2,1),
(2,1,1,2),
(3,2,3,4);

CREATE TABLE dead_stocks (ID INT,PRODUCTS_ID INT,Dead_qty INT);
INSERT INTO dead_stocks VALUES
(1,1,2),
(2,1,1),
(3,2,1);

SELECT 
    s.name AS sub_category_name, 
    SUM(DISTINCT p.AVAILABLE_QTY) AS available_qty, 
    sum(DISTINCT oi.ORDER_QTY) AS orders_qty, 
    sum(DISTINCT d.Dead_qty) AS dead_qty  
FROM subcategories s 
LEFT JOIN products p 
    ON s.id=p.subcategory_id 
LEFT JOIN orders_item oi 
    ON p.id=oi.PRODUCTS_ID
LEFT JOIN dead_stocks d
    ON p.id=d.PRODUCTS_ID 
GROUP BY s.name
ORDER BY available_qty DESC;
```

Result:

[image: Result Set_00000]

Note: dead_qty evaluates to 3 in my result set; but your result set has 4.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)